# Adding a Non-Static Class to a static List

Tags: c#, list, class, static, instance-variables

I have a Non Static class which contains a number of properties

```
private static List<FileClass> FileClassList = new List<FileClass>();
internal void AddFile(Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.FileInfo finfo)
   {
       this.FileID = FileIDCounter;
       this.Name = finfo.Name;
       this.FullName = finfo.FullName;
       this.Attributes = GetFileAttributes(finfo);
       this.CreationTime = finfo.CreationTime;
       this.Extension = finfo.Extension;
       this.isReadOnly = finfo.IsReadOnly;
       this.LastAccessTime = finfo.LastAccessTime;
       this.LastWriteTime = finfo.LastWriteTime;
       this.Length = finfo.Length;

       Interlocked.Increment(ref FileIDCounter); // As a Static value this is shared amongst all the instances of the class
       // Interlocked.Increment is the Thread Safe way of saying FileIDCounter ++;

       FileClassList.Add(this);
       if (FileClassFileAdded != null) FileClassFileAdded(this);

   }
```

Although the Class is added **FileClassList.Add(this)**; the final result is a FileClassList filled with whatever the last instance of the class contained and not the **this.Properties** values.

So, how do I add the current instance of the FileClass to the FileClassList so that the contents of the FileClassList contains the different instances of the FileClass.

Comment: Can you show how are you trying to use that list?

Comment: What do you want your list to hold?  `this.Properties` isn't referred to anywhere in your snippet, so I'm not surprised that your list doesn't have it...

Comment: @Ben probably, this.Properties are this.FileID, Name, etc. So it is possible to access them like FileClassList[i].Name ...

Comment: @JleruOHeP If that's the case, then instances of `FileClass` would serve just fine; without more info, it's impossible to know exactly what is being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what your issue most likely is...

Having this:

```
  internal void AddFile(Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.FileInfo finfo)
```

Somewhere you probably do:

```
 MyClassWhichAddsAFile cls = new MyClassWhichAddsAFile();
 cls.AddFile(fileInfo1);
 cls.AddFile(fileInfo2);
 cls.AddFile(fileInfo3);
```

While you need to do (under this design):

```
 MyClassWhichAddsAFile cls1 = new MyClassWhichAddsAFile();
 cls1.AddFile(fileInfo1);
 MyClassWhichAddsAFile cls2 = new MyClassWhichAddsAFile();
 cls2.AddFile(fileInfo2);
 ........
```

Again, I am not discussing your design here or how to do it right. I am telling you that your problem is probably comes out from this situation

Comment: Yeah - I was not re-instantiating the class - nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your design slightly askew. I don't think that AddFile should be part of FileClassList rather.
However in leiu of not having another place to hold it. I'd say do this:

```
   internal static void AddFile(Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.FileInfo finfo, FileClass theClass)
   {
       theClass.FileID = FileIDCounter;
       theClass.Name = finfo.Name;
       theClass.FullName = finfo.FullName;
       theClass.Attributes = GetFileAttributes(finfo);
       theClass.CreationTime = finfo.CreationTime;
       theClass.Extension = finfo.Extension;
       theClass.isReadOnly = finfo.IsReadOnly;
       theClass.LastAccessTime = finfo.LastAccessTime;
       theClass.LastWriteTime = finfo.LastWriteTime;
       theClass.Length = finfo.Length;

       Interlocked.Increment(ref FileIDCounter); // As a Static value this is shared amongst all the instances of the class
       // Interlocked.Increment is the Thread Safe way of saying FileIDCounter ++;

       FileClassList.Add(theClass);
       if (FileClassFileAdded != null) FileClassFileAdded(theClass);

   }
```

A better approach would be to create a contrstuctor on FileClass that takes a FileInfo and fills these properties in and call it like this:

```
var someFileClass = new FileClass(theFileInfo);
FileClass.AddFile(someClassFile);
```

and AddFile would be:

```
   internal static void AddFile(Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.FileInfo finfo, FileClass theClass)
   {

       Interlocked.Increment(ref FileIDCounter); // As a Static value this is shared amongst all the instances of the class
       // Interlocked.Increment is the Thread Safe way of saying FileIDCounter ++;

       FileClassList.Add(theClass);
       if (FileClassFileAdded != null) FileClassFileAdded(theClass);

   }
```

even then I think the AddFile should be a method on the the caller not the callee!